# Express.js access fields of serialized Form Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am struggling with accessing specific fields of my serialized formdata in my express router.

**This is my ajax request:**

```
var formData = $("#add-fut-account-form").find("select, textarea, input").serialize();
$.ajax({
  url: "/accounts/insert",
  type: "POST",
  data: {formData},
  success: function (response) {
    $("#addFutAccountResponse").append(response);
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
    alert("Error while trying to insert a new account!");
  }
})
```

**This is my router:**

```
router.post('/insert', function(req, res)
{
    var formData = req.body.formData;
    console.log(formData);
});
```

**My console.log() output:**

> email=kentor%40gmail.com&password=dsadsa&secret=123&platform=P&account-type=x&proxy=&rpm=8&threshold=3.5&optional-comment=&is-active=on

**My problem:**

How should I serialize / send / receive my formData so that I can easily access specific fields (such as email, password) from my form. I tried using `req.body.formData.email` which doesn't work (result: undefined). I know two possible ways how to solve this issue, but they appear to be a roundabout way. Thus I want to know what the best practice for handling formdata with express is.

**Edit:** I am already using the bodyParse in my app.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making the ajax as follows:

```
var formData = $("#add-fut-account-form").find("select, textarea, input").serialize();

$.ajax({
  url: "/accounts/insert",
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  success: function (response) {
    $("#addFutAccountResponse").append(response);
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
    alert("Error while trying to insert a new account!");
  }
})
```

remove the curly braces on data

Comment: You are right, thats what happened when I simplified my actual scenario. How would I pass data along with the formdata? I used data: {"formData": formData, "additionalInfo": 123} and then I wanted to access req.body.formData.email which didn't work.

Comment: you can use serializeArray, which will return you an array of objects, so you can simply push an item there, however it may change the way you access the items. you can convert the aray with a simply for loop to an actual js object. and ofcourse you can simply add a hidden input to your form :)